# Is int byte size fixed or it occupy it accordingly in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, integer, byte

I have seen some program that use `int` instead of other type like `int16_t` or `uint8_t` even though there is no need to use `int`

let me give an example, when you assign `9` to an `int`, i know that `9` takes only 1 byte to store, so is other 3 bytes free to use or are they occupied?

all i'm saying is, does `int` always takes 4-bytes in memory or it takes byte accordingly and 4-bytes is the max-size

i hope you understand what im saying.

Comment: `int` can take different sizes depending on implementation. But with a given implementation, an `int` is always same size. How would you expect it to grow if you did `int a = 9; a *= 1000000;` and suddently the value takes more than 1 byte?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure about what you're asking, but it sounds like whatever you're trying to do, it would be an extremely bad idea...

Comment: there is no language called C/C++. C and C++ are two distinct languages. Please choose one language. Only tag both when the quesiton is about interoperation between the two languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of all types is constant. The value that you store in an integer has no effect on the size of the type. If you store a positive value smaller than maximum value representable by a single byte, then the more significant bytes (if any) will contain a zero value.

The size of `int` is not necessarily 4 bytes. The byte size of integer types is implementation defined.

Answer (score 1):

> I have seen some program that use int instead of other type like int16_t or uint8_t even though there is no need to use int

This is sometimes called "sloppy typing". `int` has the drawback that its size is implementation-defined, so it isn't portable. It can in theory even use an exotic signedness format (at least until the C23 standard).

> when you assign 9 to an int, i know that 9 takes only 1 byte to store

That is not correct and there are no free bytes anywhere. Given some code `int x = 9;` then the integer constant `9` is of type `int` and takes up as much space as one, unless the compiler decided to optimize it into a smaller type. The `9` is stored in read-only memory, typically together with the executable code in the `.text` segment.

The variable `x` takes exactly `sizeof(int)` bytes (4 bytes on 32 bit systems) no matter the value stored. The compiler cannot do any sensible optimization regarding the size, other than when it is possible to remove the variable completely.

Comment: `int8_t` and `int16_t`, as mentioned in the question, have "the drawback" that they are not required to be defined, so their use is not portable. I don't have a judgmental label for that, but portability isn't binary, it's relative.

Comment: @PeteBecker That's only a concern for people who like to waste everyone's time brooding about portability to exotic DSP systems or fictional computers. The C17 standard explicitly says (7.20.1.1): "These types are optional. However, if an implementation provides integer types with widths of 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits, no padding bits, and (for the signed types) that have a two’s complement representation, it shall define the corresponding typedef names." So it's not very optional for the vast majority of real-world computers.

Comment: Also stdint.h is one of those headers that must be supported even by freestanding systems, so it literally applies to all computers except some experimental relic supercomputers from the 1960s-70s, various TI oddball DSPs etc. Nobody cares about those!

Comment: Freestanding systems are the poster child for non-portable code. `stdint.h` doesn't magically make code that's designed for a particular hardware system portable.

Comment: @PeteBecker No but it makes it possible to write portable code at all. For example I've projects where some C code from a 8 bit MCU is shared with a 64 bit C++ program for Windows, thanks to `stdint.h`. Your argument that the `stdint.h` types aren't required or portable is simply not true.

Answer (score 0):

The size of types is fixed at compile time. There is no "dynamic resizing". If you tell the compiler to use `int` it will use an integer type that is guaranteed to have at least 16bit width. However, it may be (and is most of the time) more depending on the platform and compiler you are using. You can query the byte width on your platform by using `sizeof(int)`.

There is a neat overview about the width of the different integer types at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Properties).

The `int16_t` or `uint8_t` are not core language types but convenience library defined types, that can be used if an exact bitwidth is required (e.g. for bitwise arithmetic)

Answer (score 0):

An `int` has no "free bytes". An `int` is at least 16 bits wide and the exact size depends on the target platform (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types). `sizeof(int)` is a compile time constant though. It always occupies the same number of bytes, no matter what value it holds.

The fixed width integer types (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) are useful for code that assumes a certain size of integers, because assuming certain size of `int` is usually a bug. `int16_t` is exactly 16 bits wide and `uint8_t` is exactly 8 bits wide, independent of the target platform.